# How to change tabs via a button within another tab? - KivyMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I just started coding and I'm doing a test app, but I can't change tabs when I click the button.
I needed to check if something was written in the text input, if the date was selected, and if these two options are correct, I wanted the "CalculaCompra" tab to open when clicking the button.
Can anyone help me with this? I've been racking my brain for two days with this... kkkkk

Python code

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase, MDTabs
from datetime import datetime
from locale import setlocale, LC_ALL
import sqlite3


class VamosComprar(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        pass

    def on_start(self):
        self.root.ids.tabs.add_widget(MenuApp(tab_label_text='Inicio'))
        self.root.ids.tabs.add_widget(CalculaCompra(tab_label_text='Calculadora'))
        self.root.ids.tabs.add_widget(VerListaCompra(tab_label_text='Listas'))

    def on_tab_switch(self, instance_tabs, instance_tab, instance_tab_label, tab_text):
        pass

    def irpracalcula(self):
        self.on_tab_switch = CalculaCompra(tab_label_text='Calculadora')
        self.on_tab_switch.to_widget()

    # def irpracalcula(self, tacerto=False):
    #     # verif = MenuApp()
    #     # verif.criarLista()
    #     self.tacerto = tacerto
    #     try:
    #         if self.tacerto:
    #             self.root.ids.tabs.on_tab_switch(tab_label_text='Calculadora')
    #     except Exception as erro:
    #         print(erro)


class MenuApp(MDFloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def criarLista(self):
        self.nomedalista = self.ids.nomedalista.text
        self.ondevaicomprar = self.ids.ondevaicomprar.text
        self.datalabel = self.ids.datamenu.text
        if len(self.nomedalista) <= 0:
            self.ids.nomedalista.error = True
            self.ids.nomedalista.text = ' '
        if self.datalabel == 'Insira a data':
            self.ids.datamenu.theme_text_color = 'Error'
        if len(self.nomedalista) > 0 and self.datalabel != 'Insira a data':
            self.abas = MDTabs()
            self.abas.ids.tabs.switch_tab(CalculaCompra)

            # ircalc = VamosComprar()
            # ircalc.irpracalcula(tacerto=True)

            # try:
            #     self.nomedalistadb = self.nomedalista.replace(" ", "_")
            #     banco = sqlite3.connect('listComp.db')
            #     cursor = banco.cursor()
            #     cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + self.nomedalistadb + ' ('
            #                                                              'id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,'
            #                                                              'mercado TEXT,'
            #                                                              'data TEXT,'
            #                                                              'produto TEXT,'
            #                                                              'quantidade REAL,'
            #                                                              'precounit REAL,'
            #                                                              'qtdatac REAL,'
            #                                                              'precoatac REAL,'
            #                                                              'total REAL'
            #                                                              ')')
            #
            #     banco.close()
            #     return print('Feito tudo certo')
            # except sqlite3.Error as erro:
            #     print(f'Erro: {erro}')


    def abrir_data(self):
        setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf-8')
        date_dialog = MDDatePicker()
        date_dialog.bind(on_save=self.on_save, on_cancel=self.on_cancel)
        date_dialog.open()

    # Quando salvar data muda na label
    def on_save(self, instance, value, date_range):
        # print(instance, type(value), date_range, type(str(value)))
        self.dtlabelpos = f'{str(value.day)}/{str(value.month)}/{str(value.year)}'
        self.ids.datamenu.text = self.dtlabelpos


    def on_cancel(self, instance, value):
        pass

class CalculaCompra(MDFloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class VerListaCompra(MDFloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


VamosComprar().run()
```

Code Kivy:

```
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MDToolbar:
        title: 'Vamos Comprar?'
        anchor_title: 'center'

    MDTabs:
        id: tabs
        tab_hint_x: True
        on_tab_switch: app.on_tab_switch(*args)

<MenuApp>
    id: menuapp
    MDBoxLayout:
        padding: 40, 40, 40, 40
        margin: 40, 40
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDLabel:
            id: titulomenu
            text: "Criar lista de Compras"
            halign: "center"
            font_size: 24

        MDTextField:
            id: nomedalista
            hint_text: "Nome da Lista"
            required: True
            helper_text_mode: "on_error"
            helper_text: 'Insira um nome para a lista'

        MDTextField:
            id: ondevaicomprar
            hint_text: "Onde irá fazer a compra?"

        MDBoxLayout:
            padding: 50, 50

            MDLabel:
                id: datamenu
                index: 0
                text: "Insira a data"
                valign: 'middle'

            MDIconButton:
                index: 1
                icon: 'calendar-month-outline'
                valign: 'middle'
                on_release: root.abrir_data()

        MDRaisedButton
            id: btncriarlista
            text: 'Criar Lista'
            size_hint_x: .8
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
            on_release: root.criarLista()



<CalculaCompra>
    id: calculacompra
    MDBoxLayout:
        padding: 40, 40, 40, 40
        margin: 40, 40
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDLabel:
            id: titulocalcula
            text: "Preencha os campos"
            halign: "center"
            font_size: 24

        MDTextField:
            id: produto
            hint_text: "Produto"
            required: True
            helper_text_mode: "on_error"
            helper_text: 'Insira o nome do produto'

        MDTextField:
            id: quantidade
            hint_text: "Quantidade"

        MDTextField:
            id: precounit
            hint_text: "Preço unit."

        MDBoxLayout:
            padding: 50, 50

            MDLabel:
                id: total
                index: 0
                text: "Total"
                valign: 'middle'

            MDIconButton:
                index: 1
                icon: 'cart-plus'
                valign: 'middle'
                on_release:

        MDRaisedButton
            text: 'Ver Lista'
            size_hint_x: .8
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
            on_release:

<VerListaCompra>

    MDLabel:
        id: label
        text: "ver lista"
        halign: "center"
```

I wanted that when I click on the button, it would check if there is something written in the text and if the date was selected, and when I click on the button, go to the next tab.

Answer (score 0):

In the method `criarLista()` the code:

```
    if len(self.nomedalista) > 0 and self.datalabel != 'Insira a data':
        self.abas = MDTabs()
        self.abas.ids.tabs.switch_tab(CalculaCompra)
```

is creating a new instance of `MDTabs` and calling a non-existent method (`switch_tab()`). Regardles of what you do with `self.abas`, it will have no effect on your GUI, since that new instance of `MDTabs` is not part of your GUI. You really need to access the instance of `MDTabs` that is in your `App`, and select the tab that you want. Here is one way to do that:

```
    if len(self.nomedalista) > 0 and self.datalabel != 'Insira a data':
        MDApp.get_running_app().root.ids.tabs.carousel.load_next()
```

Comment: Aaaaaaaaah .. Thank you so much, it helped me a lot .. I was racking my brain trying to fix this and it was just a line of code .. Thanks friend.